# Changing Date Informats in SAS using the Query Builder

Tags: date, sas, enterprise-guide

I want to change a date format in SAS to another date informat using the query builder.

I thought it should be as simple as:

```
INPUT(t1.In_date, MMDDYY10.)
```

But this returns the following error:

```
ERROR: INPUT function requires a character argument.
```

So I played about with it & tried a few things for example:

```
INPUT("t1.In_date", MMDDYY10.)
```

This doesn't create an error message but only produces blanks.

I've googled the error message but I can't see a way to solve this problem using the query builder.

The informat of t1.In_date is DATETIME18.

If anyone has any suggestion I would be grateful.

Comment: What format is for In_date variable ?

Comment: input wants a character as argument and returns a number. Date is already a number, so this does not work. "t1.indate" is just a string for sas (not the variable value), which cannot be changed to a number. Just use Format t1.ln_date MMDDYY10.; or change your date to a character variable like this new_date=put(t1.In_date, MMDDYY10.);

Comment: you can simply change you select query like select t1.In_date format=MMDDYY10. from table t1.

Comment: The original  informat of the variable  't1.In_date' is DATETIME18.   The function PUT so PUT(t1.In_date, MMDDYY10.) creates the following error message: 'ERROR: Date value out of range'

Comment: I feel like this is a duplicate of something... if someone wants to find that duplicate i'll happily close as dup, but I don't have the time this sec

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few problems here.

First, `informat` is the wrong terminology.  Your date variables are dates (numbers) with formats; so, you want to change their `format`.  `informat` is converting a text string to a number; `format` is changing how a number (or text string) is displayed.

Second, you have a datetime.  Datetimes are stored as the number of *seconds* from 1/1/1960, while Dates are the number of *days*.  That means that they will be not compatible format-wise.  You have to use `datepart` to convert a datetime to a date (basically, this means dividing by 86400).

So, what you want to do:

```
put(datepart(t1.in_date),mmddyy10.)
```

Comment: Thanks worked a treat :) Exactly what I was looking for & the explanation of where I was going wrong.

Comment: Spoke to soon. :)  The code  put(datepart(t1.in_date),mmddyy10.) returns a character and not a date.  Any suggestions?  Still trying a few things. Thanks Paul

Comment: Tried the following so far without luck: 
INPUT(put(datepart(t1.in_date),mmddyy10.),mmddyy10.)
MDY(put(datepart(t1.in_date),mmddyy10.),mmddyy10.)
DATE(put(datepart(t1.in_date),mmddyy10.),mmddyy10.)

Comment: I found the solution.  I did it in two steps. The first step I created a variable with DATEPART(t1.In_date).  I then went into edit mode on the worksheet and changed the format of the variable there.  Worked a treat.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, if you want the format changed but not the actual value, you need to do it like you describe, though I suspect you may be able to do it directly in query builder rather than in edit mode.